# CRM: open a website and get back result

Tags: javascript, crm

My scenario is in CRM after clicking on a button, it opens an external webpage (ASPX) as a popup, this webpage is simply a search page. And I want to get back the selection item in this page to update CRM page.

I'm using this code for open the dialog:

```
function openAddressSearch(addressType) {
    searchAddressType = addressType;
    //Allow for borders.
    var width = window.screen.width * 2/3;
    var height = window.screen.height * 2/3;
    var leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    var topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    //Open the window.
    var addressSearch = window.open("http://localhost:2402/", "AddressSearch",
        "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition +
        ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,directories=no");
/*    addressSearch.callback = function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }*/
    if (window.focus) {
        addressSearch.focus();
    }
}

function addressSearchResult(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

In the webpage (aspx), on selection button click, I call to a js function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        myClosure = function () {
            window.opener.addressSearchResult("CALLBACK");
            window.close();
        }
</script>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="m_btnSelect" Text="<%$ Resources: myResource, Select %>" OnClientClick="myClosure();"/>
```

But once clicking btnSelect, I got error at line:

```
        window.opener.addressSearchResult("CALLBACK");
```

SCRIPT70: Permission denied 
localhost:2402, line 11 character 13

What should I do to pass this error and send back result to the opener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using eventListner, in your `openAddressSearch`, add following event listener to current `window`:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (result) {
    alert("CALLBACK");
});
```

In the your external webpage:

```
window.opener.postMessage(address, "yourParentPageUrl");
```

Hope this helps.